# Finding time difference and print as string

Tags: python

1. Both starting time and ending time are in 24-hour format.
2. The starting time and ending time are always in the same day.
3. The ending time is always after the starting time.

`time_difference` that reads the starting time and ending time as input, calculates and displays the time difference.

```
def time_difference(time1, time2):
    start_hour, start_min, start_sec = time1
    end_hour, end_min, end_sec = time2
    lst = []

    if len(time2) <= 0 and len(time1)<= 0:
        return 0
    else:
        a = time2[0]-time1[0]
        b = time2[1]-time1[1]
        c = time2[2]-time1[2]
        x = (a,b,c)
        lst = []
        for i in x:
            if i not in lst:
                lst.append(i)      
        return str(lst)
```

Expression

```
time_difference((1, 2, 3), (13, 12, 11))

12:10:08'
```

This is the expected output. But how do I add the `":"` in ?  and giving the digit `08` instead of `8`

Also should work for `time_difference((11, 46, 39), (22, 31, 17))` that returns `'10:44:38'`

Comment: See my updated answer, to handle your other case.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`str.join()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) and [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format):

```
def time_difference(time1, time2):
    start_hour, start_min, start_sec = time1
    end_hour, end_min, end_sec = time2
    lst = []

    if len(time2) <= 0 and len(time1)<= 0:
        return 0
    else:
        a = time2[0]-time1[0]
        b = time2[1]-time1[1]
        c = time2[2]-time1[2]
        x = (a,b,c)
        lst = []
        for i in x:
            if i not in lst:
                lst.append(i)      

        return ":".join("{:02d}".format(x) for x in lst)
```

Example:

```
>>> time_difference((1, 2, 3), (13, 12, 11))
'12:10:08'
```

The `02d` in the string format function will make sure that each number in the list is padded to with a 0 to be exactly 2 digits long.

You must understand though that you cannot simply subtract values from `time2` with values from `time1` because that's not how time conversions are done. If you want to manually convert this, use merlin2011's answer. You should use [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) if possible, which takes into account leap years and other anomalies in handling time calculations.

Datetime example:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> str(datetime(2014, 04, 15, 22, 31, 17) - datetime(2014, 04, 15, 11, 46, 39))
'10:44:38'
```

Comment: Should also work for time_difference((11, 46, 39), (22, 31, 17))

Comment: And what exactly should that return? Your differences are negative values, what do you expect for the function to return in such case?

Comment: '10:44:38' this should be it

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your logic by returning a tuple. Also, here's another way of getting the time format, using the old-style `%` operator.

If you want to handle general times, you should convert everything into seconds, do your computation, and then convert back.

```
def time_difference(time1, time2):
    totalSecond1 = time1[0] * 3600 + time1[1] * 60 + time1[2]
    totalSecond2 = time2[0] * 3600 + time2[1] * 60 + time2[2]

    diffSeconds = totalSecond2 - totalSecond1
    hours = diffSeconds / 3600
    diffSeconds -= hours * 3600
    minutes = diffSeconds / 60
    diffSeconds -= minutes * 60
    print "%02d:%02d:%02d" % (hours,minutes,diffSeconds)
```

Note that I have modified the function to `print` and not return, because your original question said the function should "compute and print".

Answer (score 0):

you should use like this

```
def time_difference(time1, time2):
    start_hour, start_min, start_sec = time1
    end_hour, end_min, end_sec = time2
    lst = []

    if len(time2) <= 0 and len(time1)<= 0:
        return 0
    else:
        a = str(time2[0]-time1[0])
        b = str(time2[1]-time1[1])
        c = str(time2[2]-time1[2])
        if len(c) < 2:
            c = "0" + c
        if len(b) < 2:
            b = "0" + b
        x = (a,b,c)
        lst = ""
        for i in x:
            lst += i + ":"      
        return lst[:-1]
```